# ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/usr/src/app/src/index.html' in '/usr/src/app'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu

Code that I wrote, works on my Mac and it did work on the Ubuntu server, but doesn't work anymore. It's my first time setting this stuff up, so I don't really understand the problem

I've tried editing Docker-compose.yml and webpack.development.js, but errors stay the same.Even if I change every path to different, error doesn't change

code from docker-compose.yml that is responsible for frontend

```
services:
  frontend:
    build: frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/usr/src/app/src
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Rest of the code can be found in [here](https://github.com/pete02/koodi101-template), as I don't know, what you need for finding the problem

I expected it to act nicely and build the website, but it always gives the error:

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/usr/src/app/src/index.html' in '/usr/src/app'.

It works perfectly fine on my Mac, and it worked two weeks ago on the server, but now it has broken after I added on the code. Even the original code won't work anymore

I thank everyone who even looks in the problem and apologize for the time lost on this

Comment: is ./src/index.html in /usr/src/app ?

Comment: If I've understood correctly, it creates the dir as a working dir, when it's started. It also doesn't explain the sudden error, that started out of nowhere, as I pull the code from GitHub